# JList selected item to String

Tags: java, swing

Could someone tell me how to get the selected item of `JList` to a `String`? It is a single selection `JList`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
String selected = jList1.getSelectedValue();
```

Comment: hmm ... for JList (if we are talking about that) method name is getSelected_Value_

Comment: The **getSelecteditem()** is not a function that **JList** implements **WRONG ANSWER!!!**

Answer (score 18):

If you want the value of the selected item to a string you should try

```
String a = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void jList1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    Object sel =null;

    int[] selectedIx = this.jList1.getSelectedIndices();      

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIx.length; i++) {
        sel = jList1.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIx[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(sel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers given above doesn't work or are not so advanced as on today.
The following code could be used inside the ListSelectionEvent.

```
String selected = jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
jTextArea1.append("Selected item is  " + selected);
```

Comment: nothing much new compared to earlier answers, is there ;-) Including the mistake to not guard against empty selection ...