# 2 Jlists with identical entries

Tags: java, jlist

I am quite new to using Jlists, and I am quite stuck on a solution:

I have two Jlists populated with identical items, let's say a list with 'Current location' and 'Destination' and we will call them 'My house', 'Shop', 'Work', 'Pub'. I am looking for a solution: using only helper methods at this point, which will remove the entry from the second list when it is selected in the 1st list.

So, I my current location is 'Home', I want it to be removed from the 2nd 'Destination' list - because I am already 'Home' so I can't make it my destination.

It seems like a simple problem, but I can't figure out how to make this happen.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17099649/5046496 that link will show you how to get what element was select.  That should be applicable for your issue.

Comment: Thank you, guys, I found out how to do it in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

DONE IT!

The list was stored in a collection, so I copied the list to an ArrayList, iterated through the Collection with a for-each, and remove() the item that was the same as selected item and loaded the 'Destination' Jlist with the copied collection.